# How do you use "sips" at the terminal to resize an image, without upscaling?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, unix, terminal

I have some code that I've been using to resize images in Mac OS X via the command prompt (and/or quicksilver), to a maximum width or height of 500px. The only problem is that if the original image is smaller than 500px width or height, sips will upscale it. I would want it to just skip these images.

How can I make that happen?

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ARG in "$@"
    do
        sips -Z 500 -s format jpeg "$ARG" --out "${ARG%.*}.jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process the output of `sips --getProperty pixelHeight filename.ext` and `sips --getProperty pixelWidth filename.ext` and use it in a condition, only performing the resize operation if desired.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
height=`sips --getProperty pixelHeight url.png | sed -E "s/.*pixelHeight: ([0-9]+)/\1/g" | tail -1`
width=`sips --getProperty pixelWidth url.png | sed -E "s/.*pixelWidth: ([0-9]+)/\1/g" | tail -1`

if [[ $height -gt 500 || $width -gt 500 ]]; then
    growlnotify -m "large file needs reducing"
fi
```

You can do the rest on your own.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible using sips alone.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example of how to do it with the conditional statement?

Comment: @cwd See edited post

Answer (score 0):

This reads the width and height of the image in one command

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
size=($(sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight $theFile | grep -o '[0-9]*$'))

if [[ ${size[0]} -gt 500 || ${size[1]} -gt 500 ]]; then
    growlnotify -m "large file needs reducing"
fi
```